# Sorted squares of numbers in a list in O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Given a list of integers in sorted order, say, `[-9, -2, 0, 2, 3]`, we have to square each element and return the result in a sorted order.  So, the output would be: `[0, 4, 4, 9, 81]`.

I could figure out two approaches:

1. `O(NlogN)` approach - We insert the square of each element in a hashset.  Then copy the elements into a list, sort it and then return it.
2. `O(n)` approach - If there is a bound for the input elements (say -100 to -100), then we create a boolean list of size 20000 (to store -10000 to 10000).  For each of the input elements, we mark the corresponding square number as true.  For e.g., for `9` in the input, I will mark `81` in the boolean array as true. Then traverse this boolean list and insert all the true elements into a return list.  Note that in this we make an assumption - that there is a bound for the input elements.

Is there some way in which we could do it in `O(n)` time *even without assuming any bounds for the input*?

Comment: Find the sign change, square the values, interpret the list as two sorted lists, and [merge them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm).  That will be O(n).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @J.Doe With your example, `[-9, -2, 0, 2, 3]`, interpret it as `[-9, -2]`, `[0, 2, 3]` (negative; non-negative). Square both lists. `[81, 4]`, `[0, 4, 9]`. Go along the first list in reverse, go along the second list normally, and merge them up. :)

Comment: @Max, interesting! I wonder why I didn't think of _that_. :)

Comment: Another way to achieve is to use `deque.appendleft` after comparing abs(L[left]) and abs(L[right]) and decide to put in which one, and increm. the left or right pointer... (something like @Lavina Khushlani mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I can think of an `O(n)` approach

1. Split the input into 2 lists. One with negative numbers, let's call this list `A`. And one with positive numbers and 0, list `B`. This is done while preserving the input order, which is trivial : `O(n)`
2. Reverse list `A`. We do this because once squared, the greater than relation between the elements if flipped
3. Square every item of both list in place : `O(n)`
4. Run a `merge` operation not unlike that of a merge sort. : `O(n)`
5. Total: `O(n)`

Done :)

Comment: `Run a merge operation not unlike that of a merge sort. : O(n)`. This is the difficult step. How do you merge them?  I hope you're talking about in-place algorithm.

Comment: @Nawaz I'm not sure what you mean, a merge like merge sort is 5-10 lines in python.
Also how does in-place vs not in-place matter?

Comment: If you merge it in-place, then it means you're modifying the same list which is being merged with the other list. How exactly do you do that? if you still do not see it, please try to write the code to see it.

Comment: You can do it without merging in place and it would still have the same time complexity. I did not optimize for space, but it is trivial to do it. Also traditional merge sort is not in-place. But an in-place implementation is possible

Comment: If you do not do this in place, then it's trivial. It is super easy! However, if you do this in place (using `O(1)` space complexity), then it's NOT an easy task. If you think it is still easy, please try doing this and show me how it works,.

Comment: i don't undertsand why in-place vs not in place is an issue here. In place vs not in place makes no difference as far as time complexity goes, which is what the question OP was trying to achieve. And the proposed solution works at the desired time complexity, merge sort is an out of place sorting algorithm, in place is a special implementation of it. when i referred to merge sort I referred to the out of place implementation. If you want I can provide the in place implementation in a bit

Comment: please show me the code for in-place algorithm. :-)

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve it by 2 pointer technique. 1 pointer at the start and other at the end. Compare the squares and move the pointers accordingly and start allocating the max element at the end of the new list. 
Time = O(n)
Space = O(n)

Can you do it inplace ? To reduce space complexity.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some way in which we could do it in O(n) time even without assuming any bounds for the input?

Absolutely.

Since the original list is already sorted you are in luck!

given two numbers x and y

if `|x| > |y|` then `x^2 > y^2`

So all you have to do is to split the list into two parts, one for all the negative numbers and the other one for all the positive ones

Reverse the negative one and make them positive

Then you merge those two lists into one using insertion. This runs in `O(n)` since both lists are sorted.

From there you can just calculate the square and put them into the new list.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with O(n) time and space. We need two pointers. The following is the Java code:

```
public int[] sortedSquares(int[] A) {
    int i = 0; 
    int j = A.length - 1;

    int[] result = new int[A.length];

    int count = A.length - 1;
    while(count >= 0) {
        if(Math.abs(A[i]) > Math.abs(A[j])) {
            result[count] = A[i]*A[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            result[count] = A[j]*A[j];
            j--;
        }
        count--;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Start from the end ad compare the absolute values. And then create the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Solution {
        public int[] sortedSquares(int[] nums) {
            int left = 0;
            int right = nums.length -1;
            int index = nums.length- 1;
            int result[] = new int [nums.length];
            while(left<=right)
            {
                if(Math.abs(nums[left])>Math.abs(nums[right]))
                {
                    result[index] = nums[left] * nums[left];
                    left++;
                }
                else
                {
                    result[index] = nums[right] * nums[right];
                    right--;
                }
                index--;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

By using the naive approach this question will be very easy but it will require O(nlogn) complexity

To solve this question in O(n), two pointer method is the best approach.

1. Create a new result array with the same length as the given array, and store it pointer as array length
2. Assign a pointer at the start of the array and then assign another pointer at the last of the array, as we know the last element from either side will be highest

   ```
    [-9, -2, 0, 2, 3]
   ```

   compare -9  and 3 absolute value
3. if the left value then store the value to the resultant array and decrease its index value and increase the left, otherwise decrease the right.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to implement your function to have a guaranteed time complexity of O (N) regardless of the input. The idea is to use two pointers, one at the beginning and one at the end of the input list, and compare the absolute values of the numbers at those positions. Then, we append the larger square to a new list in reverse order, and move the corresponding pointer accordingly. This way, we can create a sorted list of squares in one pass without using any extra space. Here is an example of how to implement this idea in python:

```py
def sorted_squares(nums):
    # initialize an empty list to store the squares
    squares = []
    # initialize two pointers, one at the start and one at the end of the input list
    left = 0
    right = len(nums) - 1
    # loop until the pointers meet
    while left <= right:
        # compare the absolute values of the numbers at the pointers
        if abs(nums[left]) > abs(nums[right]):
            # square the larger number and append it to the front of the squares list
            squares.insert(0, nums[left] ** 2)
            # move the left pointer to the right
            left += 1
        else:
            # square the larger or equal number and append it to the front of the squares list
            squares.insert(0, nums[right] ** 2)
            # move the right pointer to the left
            right -= 1
    # return the sorted squares list
    return squares
```

Answer (score -2):

Python3 solution. time complexity - O(N) and space complexity O(1).

```
def sorted_squArrres(Arr:list) ->list:
    i = 0
    j = len(Arr)-1

    while i<len(Arr):
        if Arr[i]*Arr[i]<Arr[j]*Arr[j]:
            Arr.insert(0,Arr[j]*Arr[j])
            Arr.pop(j+1)
            i+=1
            continue

        if Arr[i]*Arr[i]>Arr[j]*Arr[j]:
            Arr.insert(0,Arr[i]*Arr[i])
            Arr.pop(i+1)
            i+=1
            continue
        else:
            if i!=j:
                Arr.insert(0,Arr[j]*Arr[j])
                Arr.insert(0,Arr[j+1]*Arr[j+1])
                Arr.pop(j+2)
                Arr.pop(i+2)
                i+=2
            else:
                Arr.insert(0,Arr[j]*Arr[j])
                Arr.pop(j+1)
                i+=1

            
 
    return Arr
        
    
X = [[-4,-3,-2,0,3,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5],[-5,-4,-3,-2,-1],[-9,-2,0,2,3]]
for i in X:
    # looping differnt kinds of inputs
    print(sorted_squArrres(i))

# outputs 
'''
[0, 4, 9, 9, 16, 25, 36]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
[0, 4, 4, 9, 81]
'''
```

Comment: This isn't leetcode