# Squares of a Sorted Array, why sorted() method is faster than O(n) method?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I am working on leetcode algorithm problem [977. Squares of a Sorted Array.](https://leetcode.com/problems/squares-of-a-sorted-array)

Why the submissions using built-in method sorted is faster than my o(n) traversal method as below?

The input is a sorted (non-decreasing order) list with integers.

sample 208 ms submission:

```
class Solution:
    def sortedSquares(self, A: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        return sorted(x*x for x in A)
```

my 260 ms submission:

```
class Solution:
    def sortedSquares(self, A: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        start = 0
        end = len(A)-1

        B = []

        while start <= end:
            if abs(A[start]) >= abs(A[end]):
                B.append(A[start] * A[start])
                start += 1
            else:
                B.append(A[end] * A[end])
                end -= 1
        B.reverse()
        return B
```

Comment: Which is your input?

Comment: Just an FYI: the algorithm dies on input `[1,3,2]` already. "O(n) sorting" is always suspicious.

Comment: @tevemadar the input array is sorted in this problem, but yes, OP definitely should have attached the problem definition.

Comment: Otherwise: the thing is that Python is not fast. It is fast when it is wiring together libraries implemented in native code. And the built-in sorting is a highly optimized mergesort, implemented in C, see https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listsort.txt for its elaborate description, and the implementation is starting at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L1070 . EDIT: as @DavidL. revealed that the input is sorted, it may be worth adding that the linked sort is said to perform extremely well on partially sorted lists.

Comment: thank you for your answers, I should have posted the problem description more detailedly. The input list in sorted should be the reason why the build-in sorted() is faster. The online judge should have tested the boundary situation or a long list, so I don't think the cnlg(n) with relatively small c is the case here.

Comment: Never put too much thought in sub-5-second benchmark results you don't have reason to trust to be meaningful. You can do without the `reverse()`: search for the boundary between negative and positive numbers and proceed "inside-out" - see [tevemadar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59086012/3789665) for doing without `abs()`.

Comment: See also: [Sorted squares of numbers in a list in O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49542410).

Answer (score 2):

Just because your algorithm has a better worst-case running time doesn't mean it will be better in practice. Python's built-in sort method is highly optimized, so its running time can be `cnlg(n)` for a relatively small `c`, while your algorithm, while being `O(n)`, could have a really high constant `d` for `dn`. We don't know what your input is, so it could be an array of, say, 10000 elements, for which `d` is still significantly larger than `clg(10000)`.

Also, as your input list is kind-of sorted (non-negative part), there might be some optimization for nearly-sorted lists in that case (not sure, never looked at Python's sort implementation).

Answer (score 2):

The time LeetCode reports is the sum over all test cases that your solution was tested against. This is very unreliable as a measure of algorithmic efficiency, because

- Most of the test cases are on small inputs,
- The overhead time taken by the judge itself is substantial, and quite variable, so even moderate differences between two measurements could just depend on random variation in this overhead.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59754210/12299000) for more discussion.

---

So if we want to compare the two algorithms' performances, it's better to do it ourselves. I did; here are my times for lists of size up to 5,000 (averaged over 1,000 runs each):

[image: times 1]

Here are my times for lists of size up to 1,000,000 (no averaging):

[image: times 2]

As you can see, using `sorted` is consistently faster for both small and large inputs, so LeetCode's comparison is actually correct this time (though perhaps just by coincidence anyway!). Your solution is indeed linear time, and these results are consistent with that. But the solution using `sorted` also appears to take linear time, and [Kelly Bundy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60142147/12299000) explains why it should.

---

My timing code is below. The times were measured using Python 3.5.2, and I get similar results with Python 3.8.1.

```py
def linear(A):
    start = 0
    end = len(A)-1
    B = []
    while start <= end:
        if abs(A[start]) >= abs(A[end]):
            B.append(A[start] * A[start])
            start += 1
        else:
            B.append(A[end] * A[end])
            end -= 1
    B.reverse()
    return B

def using_sorted(A):
    return sorted(x*x for x in A)

from timeit import timeit
from random import randint

print('n', 'linear', 'using sorted', sep='\t')
for n in range(10000, 1000001, 10000):
    data = sorted(randint(-10*n, 10*n) for i in range(n))
    t1 = timeit(lambda: linear(data), number=1)
    t2 = timeit(lambda: using_sorted(data), number=1)
    print(n, t1, t2, sep='\t')
```

Comment: I ran your code and got similar results, although they ended with about 0.95 and 0.40 seconds, so the difference is stronger for me. I'm using 3.8.1, [LeetCode uses 3.8](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-), and I think somewhere around 3.6 or 3.7 they improved `sorted` significantly by using faster comparisons if all values are numbers of the same type.

Comment: Yep, was in 3.7: "[sorted() and list.sort() have been optimized for common cases to be up to 40-75% faster.](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-square everything (so no `abs()` is needed, and especially no repeated `abs()` calls for a single element):

```
C = [x*x for x in A]

start = 0
end = len(A)-1

B = []

while start <= end:
    if C[start] >= C[end]:
        B.append(C[start])
        start += 1
    else:
        B.append(C[end])
        end -= 1
B.reverse()
return B
```

but I have not measured it. For example in-place pre-squaring may perform better.

Answer (score 1):

Python's built-in `sorted` function, which uses [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), is also **O(n) in this case**! Your input numbers are sorted and you square them. Let's look at three cases:

- If your input only contains positive numbers, then squaring them keeps the sortedness. Timsort detects that in O(n) time and doesn't do anything else.
- If your input only contains negative numbers, squaring makes it sorted in reverse. For example, `[-5, -4, -2, -1]` becomes `[25, 16, 4, 1]`. Timsort detects that and simply reverses the list. Time O(n) again.
- If your input contains both negative and positive numbers, then after squaring you'll have a descending run followed by an ascending run. Then Timsort detects both as such, reverses the descending run, and does one simple merge of the two runs. Time O(n) again.

So... both the built-in `sorted` and your own sorting are O(n). But `sorted` is implemented at the C level, which is faster and has access to shortcuts, giving it a smaller hidden constant.

Answer (score -1):

This is because Python use [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) which is kind of a adaptive sorting algorithm based on marge_sort and insertion_sort. and the time complexity is

> O(nlogn)

for Sorted() in python.

That is why Sorted() working faster then yours

Comment: The OP's solution is O(n), so this doesn't explain why `sorted` is faster.