# Python list.pop(i) time complexity?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I look up online and know that `list.pop()` has O(1) time complexity but `list.pop(i)` has O(n) time complexity. While I am writing leetcode, many people use `pop(i)` in a for loop and they say it is O(n) time complexity and in fact it is faster than my code, which only uses one loop but many lines in that loop. I wonder why this would happen, and should I use `pop(i)` instead of many lines to avoid it?

Example: Leetcode 26. Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array

My code: (faster than 75%)

```
class Solution(object):
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        left, right = 0, 0
        count = 1
        while right < len(nums)-1:
            if nums[right] == nums[right+1]:
                right += 1
            else:
                nums[left+1]=nums[right+1]
                left += 1
                right += 1
                count += 1
        return count
```

and other people's code, faster than 90%: (this guy does not say O(n), but why O(n^2) faster than my O(n)?)

https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/discuss/477370/python-3%3A-straight-forward-6-lines-solution-90-faster-100-less-memory

My optimized code (faster than 89%)

```
class Solution(object):
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        left, right = 0, 0
        while right < len(nums)-1:
            if nums[right] != nums[right+1]:
                nums[left+1]=nums[right+1]
                left += 1
            right += 1
        return left + 1
```

Comment: Time complexity is a rather theoretical concept. Using pop(i) gives a worse time complexity but the necessary memory moving is done by highly optimized compiled code (or mainly even by a single machine code instruction) and is therefore faster in many practical cases.

Comment: It's also pretty hard to say without seeing the test cases. There are 161 tests, but maybe most of them (or all of them?) are short lists where complexity barely matters. Maybe the test cases have most of the numbers to be removed at the back of the list. I think people take the "percentage faster than x" stuff from Leetcode too seriously.

Comment: this particular `pop(i)` has an average complexity of `O(K)` where K is the number of unique elements in the list (since it starts from the end, it will never need to move duplicate items when shifting.

Comment: @MichaelButscher: It's not "a single machine code instruction" (Python `list`s are much more complicated than that). But otherwise, yes, `O(n)` can hide huge constant multipliers; if the `pop(i)` solution does exactly `n**2` work due to an efficient, C implemented version of `pop`, while the `pop`-less `O(n)` equivalent written in pure Python does `100,000 * n` work due to interpreter overhead, then it would take an awfully large input before the superior algorithm (by big-O) won. The `O(n**2)` algorithm is done fairly well too (popping right-most duplicates first), so average cost is lower.

Comment: Also note: Simple math and function calls (especially to functions in built-in scope) like `len` in CPython have some of the highest overhead:real work ratios in the language. You'd save non-trivial amounts of work by doing `_len = len` outside the loop and testing with `_len(nums)` (to replace built-in lookup across two `dict`s with local lookup; can't avoid the call overhead sadly), and getting rid of the `count` variable entirely (`return left + 1` would get the same result, and avoid a third of the simple math for non-duplicates).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I  have been trying to say that for a long time, I'm amazed how concisely you put it. Exactly if is each n loop is slow his O(n) can be slower compared to someone else's. and the solution in the link has cleaver implementation to make the pop not O(n) of the original n length, but smaller subset with unique elements.

Comment: @ShadowRanger They *can* avoid the call overhead: Just do `n = len(nums)` once, before the loop.

Comment: @HeapOverflow: True. I forgot this implementation lies (was mixing up `pop` solution with this one), and doesn't actually *remove* duplicates (though it would be easy to make it not lie, with a simple `del nums[left + 1:]` just before returning [may be off-by-one, can't be bothered to check]), so `len` is stable and can be computed once and cached.

Comment: @ShadowRanger It doesn't lie. We're not supposed to actually remove duplicates. That's why the new length needs to be returned. The problem statement also says "It doesn't matter what you leave beyond the returned length."

Comment: @HeapOverflow: It lies in the name of the function, the spec just allows for lying. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Well, it's not like the name is our choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm genuinely does take O(n) time and the "pop in reverse order" algorithm genuinely does take O(n²) time. However, LeetCode isn't reporting that your time complexity is better than 89% of submissions; it is reporting your actual running time is better than 89% of all submissions. The actual running time depends on what inputs the algorithm is tested with; not just the sizes but also the number of duplicates.

It also depends how the running times across multiple test cases are averaged; if most of the test cases are for small inputs where the quadratic solution is faster, then the quadratic solution may come out ahead overall even though its time complexity is higher. @Heap Overflow also points out in the comments that the overhead time of LeetCode's judging system is proportionally large and quite variable compared to the time it takes for the algorithms to run, so the discrepancy could simply be due to random variation in that overhead.

To shed some light on this, I measured running times using [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html). The graph below shows my results; the shapes are exactly what you'd expect given the time complexities, and the crossover point is somewhere between `8000 < n < 9000` on my machine. This is based on sorted lists where each distinct element appears on average twice. The code I used to generate the times is given below.

[image: running times]

Timing code:

```py
def linear_solution(nums):
    left, right = 0, 0
    while right < len(nums)-1:
        if nums[right] != nums[right+1]:
            nums[left+1]=nums[right+1]
            left += 1
        right += 1
    return left + 1

def quadratic_solution(nums):
    prev_obj = []
    for i in range(len(nums)-1,-1,-1):
        if prev_obj == nums[i]:
            nums.pop(i)
        prev_obj = nums[i]
    return len(nums)

from random import randint
from timeit import timeit

def gen_list(n):
    max_n = n // 2
    return sorted(randint(0, max_n) for i in range(n))

# I used a step size of 1000 up to 15000, then a step size of 5000 up to 50000
step = 1000
max_n = 15000
reps = 100

print('n', 'linear time (ms)', 'quadratic time (ms)', sep='\t')
for n in range(step, max_n+1, step):
    # generate input lists
    lsts1 = [ gen_list(n) for i in range(reps) ]
    # copy the lists by value, since the algorithms will mutate them
    lsts2 = [ list(g) for g in lsts1 ]
    # use iterators to supply the input lists one-by-one to timeit
    iter1 = iter(lsts1)
    iter2 = iter(lsts2)
    t1 = timeit(lambda: linear_solution(next(iter1)), number=reps)
    t2 = timeit(lambda: quadratic_solution(next(iter2)), number=reps)
    # timeit reports the total time in seconds across all reps
    print(n, 1000*t1/reps, 1000*t2/reps, sep='\t')
```

The conclusion is that your algorithm is indeed faster than the quadratic solution for large enough inputs, but the inputs LeetCode is using to measure running times are not "large enough" to overcome the variation in the judging overhead, and the fact that the average includes times measured on smaller inputs where the quadratic algorithm is faster.

Comment: You missed something about LeetCode times: That they are *dominated* by judge overhead. The real solution time almost doesn't matter. It's hidden behind judge overhead time and it's variation. But you *can* make solution times differences visible by running the solution many times for each input. See the last few messages in the chat under @Atreyagaurav's answer.

Comment: @HeapOverflow I didn't discuss that because I'm not familiar enough with LeetCode specifically to know how their judging system works. Still, it is the actual running times that are dominated by judging overhead; the overhead cannot "dominate" in the sense of time complexity, where an `n^2` term always dominates an `n` term. What matters is still that the algorithms are compared by measuring actual running times, rather than their complexities. You make a valid point, though; I've edited to add a sentence about it.

Comment: To be clearer, as I didn't see you in the chat: I have a solution that takes about 1.7 ms of the ~80 ms that LeetCode reports. So if a quadratic solution takes 4 times as long, it won't make much difference and might even be reported as faster because LeetCode's computer happened to be less busy at that moment. That's why I somewhat disagree with your conclusion that the problem is LeetCode's *inputs* not being large enough. I think that's a red herring.

Comment: A quadratic solution doesn't generally take 4 times as long as a linear solution; 4 times linear is linear. There is always a sufficiently large input size where a quadratic algorithm will perform worse than a linear algorithm, whatever the constant factors and the constant overhead term are.

Comment: I know. I said 4 because that's approximately the factor you show at the right end of your graph. Sorry, should've mentioned that.

Comment: I see; but if you go further out, the quadratic algorithm will be 10 times as slow, or 1000 times as slow, or however much slower you need for the variation in the judge overhead not to matter. That's what I mean by "large enough". LeetCode don't report their range of input sizes, but sites like HackerRank will typically go up to 10^5 or 10^6 for problems where a linear-time solution is expected; that's significantly further than my graph goes.

Comment: As a back-of-the-envelope calculation, 10^6 is 20 times larger than 50000, so the quadratic algorithm should scale like 20^2 * 45ms = 18 seconds, and the linear algorithm should scale like 20 * 12ms = 0.24 seconds. That would definitely be enough for the variation in judge overhead not to matter.

Comment: Yeah, sure. They're not "large enough" in that sense. It just sounds like they're not large enough in the sense that they're smaller than the "crossover point". Which is not quite the case. Although it is almost. I just checked, the only case larger than 199 elements is one with 21998 elements. Sigh... LeetCode...

Comment: Nice find. In that case the judge overhead could easily vary by more than 5ms and that would cancel out the size of the actual effect; or the impact of that test could easily be mitigated by averaging over other tests with much smaller inputs where the quadratic algorithm is faster. Or both.

Comment: I think you were right about "in that sense" being unclear, so I edited the conclusion to clarify that.

Comment: Those two solutions btw actually take about 7.8 ms and 11.3 ms on LeetCode. Measured by making them solve each input 100 times so LeetCode reports about 865 ms and 1219 ms (and it's fairly stable), then subtracting 86 ms for judge overhead and input-copy overhead, then dividing by 100.

Comment: Thanks for your additions - that's quite similar to my measured times at n = 22,000. Did you measure the overhead by running a "blank" program? If you write your results in an answer, I will gladly upvote.

Comment: A "blank" program doesn't work, as LeetCode stops at the first wrong answer, so wouldn't even run the remaining 160 test cases. In other problems I measured the overhead by submitting a cheat solution just spitting out hardcoded answers, but in this problem that doesn't work because the list needs to be modified correctly. So here I determined the overhead with a little math from the results of a normal solution and the results of its 100 times magnified solution. I've done that in other problems as well and I think it matched the cheat method measuring, so I think it's reliable.

Comment: I don't feel like writing an answer. You can see I already had one and ended up ranting a lot :-). One more thing: I think LeetCode doesn't "average" but reports totals. When I submitted those "100x" solutions and LeetCode reported about 1 second, it was pretty quick, not the 161 seconds you'd expect if it were the average of the 161 test cases. And I'm fairly sure they don't run them massively in parallel.

Comment: I see; well, the effect is the same whether it's a total or an average, but you're right that my wording might not be correct.

Answer (score -3):

Just because the solution is not O(n), you can't assume it to be O(n^2).

It doesn't quite become O(n^2) because he is using pop in reverse order which decreases the time to pop every time, using pop(i) on forward order will consume more time than that on reverse, as the pop searches from reverse and in every loop he is decreasing the number of elements on the back. Try that same solution in non-reverse order, run few times to make sure, you'll see.

Anyway, regarding why his solution is faster, You have an if condition with a lot of variables, he has only used one variable `prev_obj`, using the reverse order makes it possible to do with just one variable. So the number of basic mathematical operations are more in your case, so with same O(n) complexity each of your n-loops is longer than his.

Just look at your count varible, in every iteration its value is `left+1` you could return `left+1`, just removing that would decrease n amount of `count=count+1` you have to do.

I just posted this solution and it is 76% faster

```py
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        a=sorted(set(nums),key=lambda item:item)
        for i,v in enumerate(a):
            nums[i]=v
        return len(a)
```

and this one gives [faster than 90%](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/294313516/).

```py
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        a ={k:1 for k in nums} #<--- this is O(n)
        for i,v in enumerate(a.keys()): #<--- this is another O(n), but the length is small so O(m)
            nums[i]=v
        return len(a)
```

You can say both of them are more than O(n) if you look at the for loop,
But since we are working with dublicate members when I am looping over the reduced memebers while your code is looping over all memebers. So the time required to make that unique set/dict is if lesser than time required for you to loop over those extra members and to check for if conditions, then my solution can be faster.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205989/discussion-on-answer-by-atreyagaurav-python-list-popi-time-complexity).

Comment: *"It doesn't quite become O(n^2) because he is using pop in reverse order"* - this is not correct, the pop-in-reverse-order algorithm does in fact take O(n^2) time. It just has a lower constant factor than the pop-in-forwards-order algorithm, which also takes O(n^2) time.